# Which Snitch to use for a multi-az, multi-region dse cluster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datastax-enterprise

We want to setup a 6-node DSE cluster with 1 node in a remote region. 
DSE documentation doesn't list EC2MultiregionSnitch as an option at all (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployConfigRep.html), but that's what we used in the past for DSC. What's the best practice for AWS with DSE? Which Snitch do I use?

Answer (score 2):

#### All Cassandra snitches are supported in the DataStax Enterprise product.

Here's the docs for the multi region snitch:

[multiregion snitch datastax docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c.html)

TL;DR

Multi region snitch will map regions to data centers so if you're looking to do a multi dc setup, use it.

Comment: Will it support solr / other specialized dse nodes correctly?

Comment: Yes just ensure you configure it correctly. Put search nodes on their own dc cassandra only nodes In their own dc, etc.

Comment: You can also turn on search and or analytics on all nodes on one dc if you're not worried about resource contention. Check your workload and SLAs.